# Windows service running as local service - input files?

Tags: c#, windows, service

I have a windows service program running in C#. I have configured to run it as a local service with my config files stored in \bin\release\config\configvalues.txt. But, it does not recognize this file path and throws the "System.UnauthorizedAccessException".

I believe its looking for the files in the System32 folder and since it does not have the privilege, throws out the exception. For the workaround, my service is running with "local system" to recognize the System32\config folder. To run as a local service, which file path should the config folder be available?

Comment: Why not fully qualify the path in your executable?

Answer (score 0):

Check the location of your project folder. Most likely, you'll find that it is inside your User profile folders, which the local service account does not have access to.

Deploy your project to a folder outside of any User profiles and you'll have better luck.

Comment: Not really. My project folder is C:\ (root)